# How long to hold a bond fund to be guaranteed a certain return? (mathematical proofs)

Tags: fixed-income, duration, bond-fund

**Is there a mathematical proof of how long one must hold a bond fund or ETF to be guaranteed a positive return? And of how long to be guaranteed a certain return?**
For simplicity:

- let's consider accumulating funds/ETFs, which reinvest the coupons
- let's ignore fixed maturity bond funds and consider only those which keep duration and weighted average maturity within a certain range, constantly rebalancing
- let's consider only fixed-rate bonds
- let's assume rates never become negative
- and let's ignore taxes, which change greatly from country to
  country

Another way to think about it: **when would a retail investor be better off buying single bonds, holding them to maturity, and rolling them, vs buying an accumulating bond fund / ETF?**
Of course, if you want to save to meet a certain liability in one year, buy a zero-coupon bond, but if you have a more mid-term horizon, say 5 years, and don't want to buy a 5-year zero-coupon because you think rates are likely to rise?

Let me explain:

If you buy a bond fund or ETF (other than a fixed-maturity bond ETF), it will keep its weighted average maturity and duration within a certain range; the fund itself will not have a maturity, as it rebalances constantly, buying new eligible bonds as the old ones become ineligible or mature and repay. For example, a bond ETF of bonds with 0-1 year maturity will buy new bonds as the old repay, a bond ETF of bonds with 1 - 3 year maturity will sell the bonds which reach a remaining term < 1 year and buy new ones.

With a single bond, if you hold it till maturity and the borrower doesn't default, you are guaranteed your capital back. If it's a fixed rate bond, not linked to inflation nor anything, the returns are certain if you hold it till maturity.

Not exactly so with a bond fund or ETF which doesn't have a fixed maturity.

**Of course, if rates go up, the value of your bonds goes down, but you reinvest the coupons at a higher rate. Is there a mathematical proof, for a constantly rebalancing bond fund and not a single bond, of when the two offset each other, and therefore of how long one must hold a bond fund to be guaranteed a positive return, and of how long to be guaranteed a certain return?**

I have some vague recollection of reading some proof which only holds if rates go up constantly, but I can't remember.

I have searched a number of fixed income books and couldn't find anything.

I have found some, well, I'd say marketing material, from asset managers, which basically says "please, please, don't buy single bonds, buy our bond funds" :) but doesn't really get into much detail, e.g.

https://www.northerntrust.com/japan/insights-research/2014/the-myth-of-holding-to-maturity

and

https://advisors.vanguard.com/insights/article/how-the-principal-at-maturity-myth-could-cost-you

There was also an article in this consumer forum, but no mathematical proofs or simulations: https://www.bogleheads.org/wiki/Individual_bonds_vs_a_bond_fund#Major_factors

Comment: Why are people voting to close this question without commenting? If it is such a banal question, could they please post some references to articles / books / papers etc? If it's not, why close it?